# Python reading multiple files through stdin

Tags: python

I am wanting to pipe multiple files to a python script, but I am unaware of how to do so.

```
import sys

file1 = sys.stdin.read()
file2 = sys.stdin.read()

print
print "You entered: " + file1
print
print
print "You entered: " + file2
```

Executing the script with typing input it works fine for example:

```
python input.py
FIRST
SECOND

You entered: FIRST

You entered: SECOND
```

If I pipe a file to the script it will only retrieve one of the inputs:

```
cat file1.txt file2.txt | python input.py

You entered: This is file 1
This is file 2

You entered:
```

My first assumption is it has something to do with the EOF?

Comment: `cat` con`cat`enates multiple files into *one* file and flushes them to STDOUT (by default) - `read` loads data until there is no more to read (i. e. until `EOF`)  Do you need to keep each file distinct?

Comment: `cat`'s manpage states: *cat -- concatenate and print files*. The concatenate part here is what is tripping you up; `stdin` is *one* fileobject, and no `EOF`s are sent, ever.

Comment: You cannot do what you want to do with a pipe, really, unless you insert a special marker yourself. Use filenames on the command line instead.

Comment: I am actually surprised you got this to work with manually typing, I guess that when connected to a terminal `.read()` returns early as a terminal is a stream without end.

Comment: I have just been messing around trying to figure out if there is a way to do this. I would like to try and keep them separate because this is more for learning if this is at all possible. I wasn't sure if pipe would be able to handle this or not which is why I started off this way.

Comment: Yeah, the idea of `cat` is that you turn multiple files into a continuous stream of text, so it acts like one file. You'll have to do something different if you want to keep the files separate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `read` call itself is not line buffered. It reads the maximum of `X`KB (I think `X` is something around 4K on most systems, but the exact number shouldn't be important here), or until there is nothing left to read.

When you pipe a file, you're presenting the full input at once. So, the first `read` slurps up the first `X`KB.

When you type at the terminal, the first `read` slurps until there's nothing left to read; you haven't typed it yet. The second read waits until there's something to read (when you hit enter) then reads `X` more KB.